# Join Text if criteria is TRUE EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 5 columns that could possibly contain a value & want to return in 1 cell the values from each of those columns which do contain a value (other than "") & join them in a text format, separated by " & "

The yellow column is the formula/return column & the green columns are the source columns

In the below example I would like to see "GC161 & MC263" in the yellow column

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried. If you have Excel 2019+ or Office 365, you can simply use the `TEXTJOIN` function

Comment: What about hyphen `-` in column ***Prog Code GD***?